# What is the logic of the order of the calls, in recursion in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, fibonacci

## I have a hard time understanding the order of the calls in recursive programming in Javascript

While playing around with recursive programming in Javascript, I wanted to find a solution for the Fibonacci use case. The Fibonacci is just a use case to illustrate my question. But the question is about recursive programming in JS, not about the Fibonacci algorithm.

> Given an index number N, return the corresponding value of the Fibonacci sequence, where the sequence is: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ...).

Which I did with the following solution (I know I could improve it with memoization to avoid exponential complexity):

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n <= 1) return 1;
  return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}
```

---

As I wanted to understand it better, I started to add `console.log()` in my code. And that's when the mindfucking occurred .

The order of the calls, the enumerator and the steps don't make any sense to me!

```
function fibonacci(n, caller = 'initalFibonacciCaller', step = 0) {
  console.log(caller)
  console.log('n =', n)
  console.log('step =', step)
  console.log('----------------')

  if (n <= 1) return 1;
  step++
  return fibonacci(n-1, 'fibonacciCaller1', step) + fibonacci(n-2, 'fibonacciCaller2', step);
}

console.log('=>', fibonacci(4))
```

Response:

```
initalFibonacciCaller
n = 4
step = 0
----------------
fibonacciCaller1
n = 3
step = 1
----------------
fibonacciCaller1
n = 2
step = 2
----------------
fibonacciCaller1
n = 1
step = 3
----------------
fibonacciCaller2
n = 0
step = 3
----------------
fibonacciCaller2
n = 1
step = 2
----------------
fibonacciCaller2
n = 2
step = 1
----------------
fibonacciCaller1
n = 1
step = 2
----------------
fibonacciCaller2
n = 0
step = 2
----------------

5
```

How come that as from `step3` `fibonacciCaller2`, the `n` start to increase and the `steps` start to decrease ?

This is probably due to my lack of understanding of how Javascript works, but I would love a good explanation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a different approach and visualize the side of the recursion by adding angle brackets as step and get the order of the calling with a side.

for example the recurion goes first all to the left side of bifurcation and then at the last step to the right side.

```js
function fibonacci(n, step = { s: 0 }, sides = '') {
    console.log(++step.s, n, sides);
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    return fibonacci(n - 1, step, sides + '< ') + fibonacci(n - 2, step, sides + '> ');
}

console.log(fibonacci(5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's already clearer with the sides ! Yet I still don't understand why the enumerator is `0` at step 6 (so the first right side of the bifurcation) ?

Comment: because at step 4, you have the value `2` and the right side is `n - 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to visualize this, by adding a different flavor of logging than your `steps`,  using an indentation parameter instead, gives a result like this:

```
fibonacci (4)
    left:
        fibonacci (3)
            left:
                fibonacci (2)
                    left:
                        fibonacci (1)
                        ==> 1    -- fibonacci (1) (base case)
                    right:
                        fibonacci (0)
                        ==> 1    -- fibonacci (0) (base case)
                ==> 1 + 1 ==> 2    -- fibonacci (2)
            right:
                fibonacci (1)
                ==> 1    -- fibonacci (1) (base case)
        ==> 2 + 1 ==> 3    -- fibonacci (3)
    right:
        fibonacci (2)
            left:
                fibonacci (1)
                ==> 1    -- fibonacci (1) (base case)
            right:
                fibonacci (0)
                ==> 1    -- fibonacci (0) (base case)
        ==> 1 + 1 ==> 2    -- fibonacci (2)
==> 3 + 2 ==> 5    -- fibonacci (4)

Returning 5
```

You can see from this that we proceed down the left-hand calls (the first recursive step) all the way before we back up a level and do the right-hand ones, back up another level and do its right-hand ones, etc.

You can see how I added the logging in this snippet:

```js
const log = (indent, message) => 
  console.log (Array(indent * 2).fill('  ').join('') + message)

function fibonacci(n, indent = 0) {
  log (indent, `fibonacci (${n})`)
  if (n <= 1) {
    log(indent, `==> 1    -- fibonacci (${n}) (base case)`)
    return 1;
  }
  log (indent + 1, 'left:')
  const left = fibonacci(n-1, indent + 2) 
  log (indent + 1, 'right:')
  const right = fibonacci(n-2, indent + 2)
  const result = left + right;
  log(indent, `==> ${left} + ${right} ==> ${result}    -- fibonacci (${n})`)
  return result
}

console .log (``, `Returning ${fibonacci(4)}`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```